# ubuntu server 14.04 LTS too slow

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, mysql, proftpd

Last two weeks my ubuntu server is too slow. It happens every day. All the services are pretty slow or died. Reboot server helps for 4-5 hours and after that issue occurs again.

I've made screenshots for `top` command:

1. right after reboot server (all services like proftpd, apache, mysql work fine): https://gyazo.com/3714f56db283baf9bf169dcabc08a152
2. after 8-9 hours: https://gyazo.com/0efce9186e6459f9451a3e25acf1a5be
   As I see free memory were decreased. Maybe that is the root of the issue? But what cause it ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Does `top` tell you anything useful about CPU & RAM usage?

Comment: @MarkWilliams, which command should I use then ? I'm newbee in ubuntu server

Comment: Use `top` (from command line) - this will give a whole page display (ie more if you maximise the window) of what is using your resources up. There is an inbuilt help menu, I won't re-type it here!

Comment: Server was rebooted again 10 minutes ago. Here is a screenshot: https://gyazo.com/a7c306bea7c95759a0f117932da2f747

Comment: Nothing hogging it yet - but then, you said it works well when rebooted. Check again in a few hours & see what's changed - particularly the 'mem' column, you can make it sort on that by typing '>'.  3Gb + 2Gb swap is low for a server.

Comment: If provided screenshots are not enough - I definitely will provide new ones. Can you also please provide full command with '>' sign ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First to check your hardware.  Run [MemTest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) at least 24 hours to make sure your memory is not root cause.

Due to sendmail-mta hangs, my experience is due to DNS issue (by `gethostent`) or YP/NIS issue (if you have installed `nis`).

Try this command to see whether you have installed `nis`.

```
dpkg -l nis
```

If yes, try to remove it by `apt-get remove nis` if you don't need nis service.  Otherwise, you might need to check YP/NIS settings. (like `nisdomainname` to see your YP/NIS domain is properly set, and `ypwhich` to see if NIS client is working)

Try this commands to see whether it's `gethostent` issue:

```
# to see if it's very slow when system is abnornormal.
ping www.google.com
```

If you have root permission, you might want to use `strace` to debug `sendmail-mta` to verify which syscall blocks your process, and it would help a lot.

Comment: just rebooted server, therefore all is ok for now: https://gyazo.com/8979cef81c1a660794018721bfc2924f. Will wait for 4-5 hours and I'll provide a new screenshots with strace command. P.S.: I've root permissions. Also I'm not sure there is a hardware (memory) related issue - but I'll definitely check that next week

Comment: proftpd and website are very slow again. Here are more recent screenshots: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByD5pJyyZkQlQjhSUVJ2TFRCNmM, https://gyazo.com/1dc1f0f0ac6cbb534ca0ae1011b199bb, https://gyazo.com/b50cf3e045e66685abc024bb0d3525e1, https://gyazo.com/5996eef3c032438dd9e551341d097a5f. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshots are showing a server with modest RAM, but apparently OK as you aren't using swap space even on the 10 hour one, and it's usually swap that kills a computer's speed if it's a memory problem.
I think you need to run & monitor `top` to see if it varies much & uses swap space when it is slow, also to see if there's a CPU hog.
I use a utility called gkrellm as a side-bar which shows up disk & network accesses as well, this might shed more light on what's slowing it down.
There is also `slabtop` which is a lot less easy to interpret, but gives RAM use in more detail.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/8fa1d9f3261756965e9d8a0eed3c89a1, slabtops: https://gyazo.com/8d1f35a658f48b45fa3f549924bf27c5. Users complain again that proftpd and website don't work :(.

Comment: proftpd and website are very slow again. Here are more recent screenshots: drive.google.com/open?id=0ByD5pJyyZkQlQjhSUVJ2TFRCNmM, gyazo.com/1dc1f0f0ac6cbb534ca0ae1011b199bb, gyazo.com/b50cf3e045e66685abc024bb0d3525e1, gyazo.com/5996eef3c032438dd9e551341d097a5f. Please advise. Thank you.